# Problem Polygon Line Intersection - SAGA QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-3, qgis-plugins, qgis-processing, saga

I have a ShapeFile with a series of polygons (ex: the yellow line is the common boundary between 2 polygons). I have another ShapeFile that contains a line (Pink) which crosses the limit line of these polygons several times, therefore delimiting several small areas (paint in grey).How can I generate these polygons for calculate the area of ​​the polygons? (I try Polygon Line Intersection - SAGA in QGIS 3.28.6 but...it only intersected some parts).
[image]